# I fail to understand the following assignment

Tags: c

```
char errorString[20];
*(UInt32*)(errorString + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(statusCode);
```

I found this in a book about audio programming and, considering `CFSwapInt32HostToBig` returns an Int32, I can't understand why does it need to make that strange cast and why it assigns starting with the address of the second element (+1) in the `char` buffer.

What will `errorString` contain after this assignment?

Comment: Since this involves platform specific types we need to know the platform you are on and compiler options you used.

Comment: @Hogan `UInt32` is the only type here, and I think we can surmise that it's a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - sure, but we can't know the endian of the machine so we can't say what exactly errorString[1] will be.  Which seems to me a key point of the question

Comment: @Hogan again untrue, since he's assigning the result of a function called `CFSwapInt32HostToBig` which presumably produces a big-endian result regardless of machine endianness.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - that is an assumption and if true compiler options could change that (as I said.)

Comment: @Patatoswatter -- Instead of getting bogged down in a game of details, look at the point of my comment.  Meda is working in an area that requires attention to lots of Machine details -- I don't know / think he realizes that based on the question -- this was my real point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't understand why does it need to make that strange cast

The cast is necessary to avoid truncating the data to a single `char`: if you drop the cast, like this

```
*(errorString + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(statusCode);
```

the assignment will modify a single `char`. Effectively, it's this:

```
*(errorString + 1) = (char)CFSwapInt32HostToBig(statusCode);
```

which is not what the author of the code wanted.

As far as adding a byte goes, the answer depends on the use of `errorString`: most likely, some other piece of data is supposed to go there.

Comment: @Hogan WRONG --- The second line is what would happen if you omit the cast.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The answer is very unclear. It looks like you're giving an alternative implementation for his code, but instead it's just a tangent.

Comment: @dasbinkenlight - ah I see this is an answer to "why is the cast there?"  I guess that was not 100% clear to me -- thought it was the answer to "what does this do?"

Comment: @Potatoswatter I added a quote from the OP to make it clear what part of the question I'm answering.

Answer (score 7):

`errorString+1` (which is of type `char*`) is casted to pointer to `UInt32` and then dereferenced. Hence, the four consequent bytes of `errorString`, from the second to the fifth (`errorString[1]` ... `errorString[4]`), will contain a binary representation of an integer that is result of `CFSwapInt32HostToBig(statusCode)`.

Answer (score 3):

`CFSwapInt32HostToBig` returns a value of a 32-bit type but `errorString` is an array of `char`.

The programmer wants to store the 4 bytes into the array of `char` starting from position `&errorString[1]`.

Note that is not safe and should be avoided as it breaks aliasing rules and may break alignment.